# Cannot assign value of type String:NSObject to type String:NSObject

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, swift2, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary/array, looks like this:

```
var myArray: [[String:NSObject]] = []

let newItem = [
                [
                    "caseNumber" : caseToAdd,
                    "formType" : formType,
                    "caseStatus" : caseStatus,
                    "caseDetails" : caseDetails,
                    "caseLUD" : caseLUD,
                    "friendlyName" : ""
                ]]

//Add new item to existing array
            myArray += newItem
```

This works fine, I can access the items etc. But now I want to save it to NSUserDefaults so I can access it again in the future. I can save it just fine, but trying to load it again is giving me an issue:

```
myArray = HelperSavedData().loadMyCasesFromNSUserDefaults
```

Here is the HelperSavedData class:

```
public class HelperSavedData {

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    public func saveMyCasesToNSUserDefaults(input:NSObject){
        defaults.setObject(input, forKey: "myArray")
        defaults.synchronize()
    }

    public func loadMyCasesFromNSUserDefaults() -> [[String:NSObject]]? {
        if let savedArray = defaults.valueForKey("myArray") {
            return ((savedArray) as! [[String : NSObject]])
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error:

> Cannot assign value of type () -> [[String: NSObject]]? to type [[String: NSObject]]

Comment: which line has error?

Comment: myArray += newItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign an optional type to a non-optional type without some amount of unwrapping.

You've defined `myArray` as being a non-optional array of dictionaries.

```
var myArray: [[String:NSObject]] = []
```

The variable, `myArray` can never be `nil`.

You've defined `loadMyCasesFromNSUserDefaults()` as returning an optional array of dictionaries.

```
public func loadMyCasesFromNSUserDefaults() -> [[String:NSObject]]?
```

That is to say, this method *could* return `nil`.

So we have to decide what makes most sense in terms of how to handle our variables.  Does it make sense to allow `nil` to be assign into our `myArray` variable?  If so, make it an optional as other answers suggest:

```
var myArray: [[String:NSObject]]?
```

But maybe it never makes sense for `myArray` to be `nil`.  In this case, don't change the declaration of `myArray`.  Instead, determine how we handle the case in which your method returns `nil`.

We could say... we only want to assign into `myArray` if we load a non-nil array from the method:

```
var myArray = [[String:NSObject]]()

if let loadedArray = loadMyCasesFromNSUserDefaults() {
    myArray = loadedArray
}

myArray += newItem
```

Or we could use the Nil-Coalescing operator and assign a default value into `myArray` if `loadMyCasesFromNSUserDefaults()` returns `nil`.

```
var myArray = loadMyCasesFromNSUserDefaults() ?? [newItem]
```

And there are plenty of other ways to deal with `nil` and optionals as well.

What is key here, is we need to make a few decisions.

- Should `myArray` ever allowed to be `nil`?  Does that make sense?
- If `myArray` shouldn't be `nil`, what makes sense for handling the case in which our method returns `nil`?  How do we want to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an **optional value** from `loadMyCasesFromNSUserDefaults()` and trying to save it in a **non-optional value**. Try changing the `myArray` declaration like this

`var myArray: [[String:NSObject]]?`

Comment: Ah! Thank you. But now this doesn't work: myArray += newItem

Comment: I think the problem is where you're creating the dictionary array `newItem`. It's a different issue. Consider opening a new question.

Comment: That's not the problem, @ebby94.

Answer (score -1):

`loadMyCasesFromNSUserDefaults()` return `[[String:NSObject]]?` which is an optional value ,pls try `var myArray?: [[String:NSObject]] = []`